# CSS Shape with Gradient Next Adjacent to Container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, linear-gradients

I'm trying to put together a specific design for a website we are building. The header needs a parallelogram shape above it, and a trapezium to the right of the container, as shown below.

[image: Header Example]

I've managed to add the parallelogram above the container, but i'm struggling to get the element to the right of the container. The following shows what i've done.

HTML

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      Content Here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.container {
  width: 700px;
}

.container:before {
  content:'';
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    transform: skew(45deg);
    background: #254896;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #254896, #2c2b5b 100%);
    display: block;
}

.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;

}

.row:before {
    content:'';
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    border-image-source: linear-gradient(90deg, #FF0000, #940202);
    border-image-slice: 1;
    border-top: 30px solid red;
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    left: 800px;
    top: 30px;
}

.col {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/scarrott/vgtpna14/

The issues i'm having are:

- Getting the red shape to sit neatly to the right of the container regardless of screen size.
- Putting a gradient fill on the trapezium shape. If I use border-image-source it makes the shape a rectangle.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea using multiple background. I used `400px` instead of `700px` to better see in the snippet

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  --w:400px;
  max-width: var(--w);
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

.container:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 0;
  width: calc(50vw + var(--w)/2);
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  transform: skew(45deg);
  transform-origin: top;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(90deg, #254896, #2c2b5b 100%) top left/var(--w) 50%, 
    linear-gradient(90deg, #FF0000, #940202) bottom right /calc(100% - var(--w)) 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
}

.col {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      Content Here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another idea with clip-path:

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  --w:400px;
  max-width: var(--w);
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

.container:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 0;
  width: calc(50vw + var(--w)/2);
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  clip-path:polygon(0 0, calc(var(--w) - 20px) 0,var(--w) 50%,100% 50%,100% 100%,calc(var(--w) + 20px) 100%,var(--w) 50%, 20px 50%);
  background: 
    linear-gradient(90deg, #254896, #2c2b5b 100%) top left/var(--w) 50%, 
    linear-gradient(90deg, #FF0000, #940202) bottom right /calc(100% - var(--w)) 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
}

.col {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      Content Here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Including bootstrap

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  --w: 540px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    --w: 720px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    --w: 960px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    --w: 1140px;
  }
}

.container:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 0;
  width: calc(50vw + var(--w)/2);
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(var(--w) - 20px) 0, var(--w) 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, calc(var(--w) + 20px) 100%, var(--w) 50%, 20px 50%);
  background: 
    linear-gradient(90deg, #254896, #2c2b5b 100%) top left/var(--w) 50%, 
    linear-gradient(90deg, #FF0000, #940202) bottom right /calc(100% - var(--w)) 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      Content Here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks great. The only issue is that my page isn't fixed width. It's usings standard bootstrap breakpoints. How can i set the --w variable to match the width of the main container? I've not used CSS variables much.

Comment: @scarrott use media query to update like bootstrap is doing (will update later including bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to to have the 2 parallelogram shapes inside the container div with specified percentages.

```
    .row::before {
      content: '';
        width: calc(70% - 14px);
        height: 30px;
        transform: skew(45deg);
        background: #254896;
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #254896, #2c2b5b 100%);
    }

    .row::after {
        content: '';
        width: calc(30% - 14px);
        height: 30px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 30px;            
        transform: skew(45deg);
        background: red;
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, #FF0000, #940202);
    }
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/modgpuLc/3/)**

Comment: Unfortunately that does push the content off centre. I can definitely see some uses for this in other circumstances though.